# Why does indexing a pandas series directly with [-1] yield a KeyError, but using iloc[-1] does not?

Tags: python, pandas, series

## Problem description

I am attempting to **extract** the **first and last element of a pandas series** for an assertion regarding the data integrity. However, when I do not directly use `iloc` to access the element in the `pd.Series` object I get a `KeyError: -1``.

## Code Snippet

```
for year in df['year'].unique():
    yearly_slice = df[df['year'] == year]

    if len(yearly_slice) > 1:
        fst = yearly_slice[foo].iloc[-1] # Yields the expected result
        fst = yearly_slice[foo][-1]      # Raises KeyError: -1
        
# Rest of code ...
```

## Further background

From my understanding the results should not differ, especially since I am not iterating over yearly_slice and am just attempting to read the data (I know that for writing there is a difference).

I have already checked the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#basics), but it did not provide any information on the behavior of pandas when using `[]` with a negative offset.

Comment: `yearly_slice[foo][-1]` should work, which pandas version did you use?

Comment: Also given your code you might be looking for `df.groupby('year')[foo].agg(['min', 'max'])` (or `df.groupby('year')[foo].agg(['min', 'max', 'size'])` if you also want to check the size of the groups)

Comment: And actually, `for yearly_slice in df['year'].unique():` yields items from an array, so what exactly is the input DataFrame? What are `type(yearly_slice)` and `df.head().to_dict('tight')`?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes I am aware of groupby and aggregation and utilizing it outside of the provided snippet. That was however not my question.

You are correct I forgot a relevant part of the snippet regarding to the input df.

Comment: Furthermore, the post you linked when closing the question concerns itself with the difference between `loc` and `iloc`, which is distinctly different from `[]` which is an alias for `__getitem__` as you can see by consulting the link to the pandas documentation I provided.

Comment: This is pretty much the same, `[]` acts as `loc` on a Series. I added an example below. In summary only use `iloc` or the underlying array if you must slice by position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because `-1` is not a key in your index.

Using `[-1]` **may** work if you have a non-range index (then pandas infers that you're using a positional indexer), but this is not a good practice.

See for example:

```
pd.Series([0,1,2], index=list('abc'))[-1]
# 2

pd.Series([0,1,2])[-1]
# KeyError: -1
```

In summary, always use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) for positional indexing, this is the only safe way.

Alternatively, using the underlying numpy array:

```
pd.Series([0,1,2]).values[-1]

pd.Series([0,1,2]).to_numpy()[-1]
```